# pandas value_counts applied to each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` with numerous columns (≈30) from an external source (csv file) but several of them have no value or always the same. Thus, I would to see quickly the `value_counts` for each column, how can i do that?

For example

```
  Id, temp, name
1 34, null, mark
2 22, null, mark
3 34, null, mark
```

Would return me an object stating that

- Id: 34 -> 2,  22 -> 1
- temp: null -> 3
- name: mark -> 3

So I would know that temp is irrelevant and name is not interesting (always the same)

Comment: Loop over the columns and print a `value_counts` for each?

Comment: What @joris said. There's an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5381) To add a `value_counts` method to DataFrame, but there are a few issues to do with index alignment.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For the dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[34, 'null', 'mark'], [22, 'null', 'mark'], [34, 'null', 'mark']], columns=['id', 'temp', 'name'], index=[1, 2, 3])
```

the following code

```
for c in df.columns:
    print "---- %s ---" % c
    print df[c].value_counts()
```

will produce the following result:

```
---- id ---
34    2
22    1
dtype: int64
---- temp ---
null    3
dtype: int64
---- name ---
mark    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer. I thought it was possible to do it without a loop but it seems it is not. (and yep i've seen the issue mentioned, hope it will be possible soon :)).

Comment: Actually, why not do it with a map like :
map(lambda x : x.value_counts(), mdf.columns)

Comment: @Edouard, I think code in your last comment needs to be `map(lambda x : mdf[x].value_counts(), mdf.columns)`

Comment: `to_frame()` and  `display()` functions would  be useful for an enhanced  output , eg: `for c in df.columns: display(df[c].value_counts().to_frame())`

Answer (score 14):

you can use `df.apply` which will apply each column with provided function, in this case counting missing value. This is what it looks like,

`df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().value_counts())`

Comment: This creates a series with all three columns. How to split the columns and create a dataframe with 3 columns?

Answer (score 10):

A nice way to do this and return a nicely formatter series is combining `pandas.Series.value_counts` and `pandas.DataFrame.stack`.

For the DataFrame

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[[34, 'null', 'mark'], [22, 'null', 'mark'], [34, 'null', 'mark']], columns=['id', 'temp', 'name'], index=[1, 2, 3])
```

You can do something like

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack()
```

In this code, `df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())` applies `value_counts` to every column and appends it to the resulting `DataFrame`, so you end up with a `DataFrame` with the same columns and one row per every different value in every column (and a lot of `null` for each value that doesn't appear in each column).

After that, `T` transposes the `DataFrame` (so you end up with a `DataFrame` with an index equal to the columns and the columns equal to the possible values), and `stack` turns the columns of the `DataFrame` into a new level of the MultiIndex and "deletes" all the `Null` values, making the whole thing a `Series`.

The result of this is

```
id    22      1
      34      2
temp  null    3
name  mark    3
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

Code like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[34, 'null', 'mark'], [22, 'null', 'mark'], [34, 'null', 'mark']], columns=["id", 'temp', 'name'], index=[1, 2, 3]) 
result2 = df.apply(pd.value_counts)
result2
```

will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [@Jagie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47376125/512497)'s reply but in addition:

1. Put zero for values absent in a column
2. Convert the counts to integer

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data=[[34, 'null', 'mark'], [22, 'null', 'mark'], [34, 'null', 'mark']],     
        columns=["id", 'temp', 'name'], 
        index=[1, 2, 3]
    )
    result2 = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```
fillna(0).astype(int)
```

to

```
fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```