# How to get value counts for multiple columns at once in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Given a Pandas DataFrame that has multiple columns with categorical values (0 or 1), is it possible to conveniently get the value_counts for every column at the same time?

For example, suppose I generate a DataFrame as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))
```

I can get a DataFrame like this:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  0  1  1  0
1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  0
3  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  1
5  0  1  1  0
6  0  1  1  1
7  1  0  1  0
8  1  0  1  1
9  0  1  1  0
```

How do I conveniently get the value counts for every column and obtain the following conveniently?

```
   a  b  c  d
0  6  3  2  6
1  4  7  8  4
```

My current solution is:

```
pieces = []
for col in df.columns:
    tmp_series = df[col].value_counts()
    tmp_series.name = col
    pieces.append(tmp_series)
df_value_counts = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1)
```

But there must be a simpler way, like stacking, pivoting, or groupby?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Just call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and pass [`pd.Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts):

```
In [212]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
Out[212]:
   a  b  c  d
0  4  6  4  3
1  6  4  6  7
```

Comment: How would one add dropna=False to this?

Comment: na will not get dropped by default

Comment: Same question, how would you add "normalize=True"? --- sorry found the solution: df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, normalize=True)

Answer (score 49):

There is actually a fairly interesting and advanced way of doing this problem with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['table', 'chair', 'chair', 'lamp', 'bed'],
                   'b': ['lamp', 'candle', 'chair', 'lamp', 'bed'],
                   'c': ['mirror', 'mirror', 'mirror', 'mirror', 'mirror']})

df

       a       b       c
0  table    lamp  mirror
1  chair  candle  mirror
2  chair   chair  mirror
3   lamp    lamp  mirror
4    bed     bed  mirror
```

We can first melt the DataFrame

```
df1 = df.melt(var_name='columns', value_name='index')
df1

   columns   index
0        a   table
1        a   chair
2        a   chair
3        a    lamp
4        a     bed
5        b    lamp
6        b  candle
7        b   chair
8        b    lamp
9        b     bed
10       c  mirror
11       c  mirror
12       c  mirror
13       c  mirror
14       c  mirror
```

And then use the crosstab function to count the values for each column. This preserves the data type as ints which wouldn't be the case for the currently selected answer:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df1['index'], columns=df1['columns'])

columns  a  b  c
index           
bed      1  1  0
candle   0  1  0
chair    2  1  0
lamp     1  2  0
mirror   0  0  5
table    1  0  0
```

Or in one line, which expands the column names to parameter names with `**` (this is advanced)

```
pd.crosstab(**df.melt(var_name='columns', value_name='index'))
```

Also, `value_counts` is now a top-level function. So you can simplify the currently selected answer to the following:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

Comment: crosstab is nice because it leaves you with integers, though we can also get that with `df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 17):

To get the counts only for specific columns:

`df[['a', 'b']].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)`

where df is the name of your dataframe and 'a' and 'b' are the columns for which you want to count the values.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that selects all categorical columns and makes a dataframe with all value counts at once:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'fruits': ['apple', 'mango', 'apple', 'mango', 'mango', 'pear', 'mango'],
'vegetables': ['cucumber', 'eggplant', 'tomato', 'tomato', 'tomato', 'tomato', 'pumpkin'],
'sauces': ['chili', 'chili', 'ketchup', 'ketchup', 'chili', '1000 islands', 'chili']})

cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include=object).columns.tolist()
(pd.DataFrame(
    df[cat_cols]
    .melt(var_name='column', value_name='value')
    .value_counts())
.rename(columns={0: 'counts'})
.sort_values(by=['column', 'counts']))

                            counts
column      value   
fruits      pear            1
            apple           2
            mango           4
sauces      1000 islands    1
            ketchup         2
            chili           4
vegetables  pumpkin         1
            eggplant        1
            cucumber        1
            tomato          4
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this code:

```
for i in heart.columns:
    x = heart[i].value_counts()
    print("Column name is:",i,"and it value is:",x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your solution wrapped in one line looks even simpler than using groupby, stacking etc:

```
pd.concat([df[column].value_counts() for column in df], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying the value_counts function gave be unexpected / not the most readable results. But this approach seems super simple and easy to read:

```py
df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].value_counts()
```

Here is an example of results if the cols have boolean values:

```
col1               col2         col3
False              False        False        1000
                   True         False        1000
True               False        False        1000
                                True         1000
                   True         False        1000
                                True         1000
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
for column in df.columns:
     print("\n" + column)
     print(df[column].value_counts())
```

[link to source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197324/pandas-value-counts-applied-to-each-column)

Comment: I would enhance this answer by choosing how many of the top values you'd like to see (5 in my example), and by including NaN values: `df[column].value_counts(dropna= False).nlargest(5)`

Answer (score 1):

you can list the column name

`list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`

then run a for loop using value_counts() function

```
for i in list:
  print(df[i].value_counts())
  print("\n")
```

you can also use this method given below

```
for column in df.columns:
 print("\n" + column)
 print(df[column].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this to see if there was a better way of doing what I was doing. Turns out calling `df.apply(pd.value_counts)` on a DataFrame whose columns each have their own many distinct values will result in a pretty substantial performance hit.

In this case, it is better to simply iterate over the non-numeric columns in a dictionary comprehension, and leave it as a dictionary:

```py
types_to_count = {"object", "category", "string"}
result = {
    col: df[col].value_counts()
    for col in df.columns[df.dtypes.isin(types_to_count)]
}
```

The filtering by `types_to_count` helps to ensure you don't try to take the `value_counts` of continuous data.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which can be done:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 4)), columns=list('abcd'))
l1 = pd.Series()
for var in df.columns:
    l2 = df[var].value_counts()
    l1 = pd.concat([l1, l2], axis = 1)
l1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some columns are subsequent in hierarchy, in that case I recommend to "group" them and then make counts:

```
# note: "_id" is whatever column you have to make the counts with len()
cat_cols = ['column_1', 'column_2']
df.groupby(cat_cols).agg(count=('_id', lambda x: len(x)))
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>column_1</th>
      <th>column_2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" valign="top">category_1</th>
      <th>Excelent</th>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Good</th>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bad</th>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="5" valign="top">category_2</th>
      <th>Happy</th>
      <td>48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Good mood</th>
      <td>158</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Serious</th>
      <td>62</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Sad</th>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Depressed</th>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Bonus: you can change len(x) to x.nunique() or other lambda functions you want.*

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be nice if it could be implemented in a way that works also for columns with different sets of values.

This code will generate a dataframe with hierarchical columns where the top column level signifies the column name from the original dataframe and at the lower level you get each two columns one for the values and one for the counts.

```
def val_cnts_df(df):
    val_cnts_dict = {}
    max_length = 0
    for col in df:
        val_cnts_dict[col] = df[col].value_counts()
        max_length = max(max_length, len(val_cnts_dict[col]))

    lists = [[col, prefix] for col in val_cnts_dict.keys() for prefix in ['values', 'counts']]
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(lists, names=['column', 'value_counts'])

    val_cnts_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((max_length, len(columns))), columns=columns)

    for col in val_cnts_dict:
        val_cnts_df[col, 'values'] = val_cnts_dict[col].reset_index()['index']
        val_cnts_df[col, 'counts'] = val_cnts_dict[col].reset_index()[col]
        
    return val_cnts_df
```

Example of results:

```
autos = pd.DataFrame({'brand': ['Audi', 'Audi', 'VW', 'BMW', 'VW', 'VW'],
                      'gearbox': ['automatic', 'automatic', 'manual', 'automatic',
                                  'manual', 'manual'],
                     'doors': [5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 5]})

print(val_cnts_df(autos))
```

````
column        brand            gearbox        doors       
value_counts  values counts    values counts  values counts
0                 VW     3  automatic    3.0    5.0    5.0
1               Audi     2     manual    3.0    2.0    1.0
2                BMW     1        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Don't love any of the answers above. Indices get jumbled together. Think something like this is better:

```
def multi_col_value_counts(df, n_rows=10):
    vl_cnts = []
    for col in df.select_dtypes(exclude=["number", 'datetime']):
        vl_cnt = (
            df[col]
            .value_counts(dropna=False)
            .head(n_rows)
            .rename(f"{col}_row_count")
            .reset_index()
        )
        vl_cnts.append(vl_cnt)

    out_df = pd.concat(vl_cnts, axis=1)
    return out_df
```

Can obviously add args to the func as needed. Personally I always like to see nans counts, so included them by default

Answer (score -1):

solution which can be done:

```
for count_unqiue in df1[df1.columns]: print(df1[count_unqiue].value_counts(dropna=False).sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(5))
```

another appoach

```
for col in df1.columns[0:]:
    print(col, ': ', len(df1[col].unique()), 'labels')
```