# Count Partial match in each DataFrame Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have Data frame in which I want to count occurrence of some word per each column.
Per one coumn I can do:

```
df['Col1'].str.contains('test').value_couns()
```

or

```
df[df['Col1'].str.contains('test')]['Col1'].count()
```

and i get count for particular column.

How can I get it for all columns?
I would like to avoid do it manually per each column since there are quite a few of them.

[image]

Expected output

[image]

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589829/how-to-get-value-counts-for-multiple-columns-at-once-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: provide sample imput and expected output

Comment: Added in Question

Comment: I think I have something which is work almost as I wanted: df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('test').value_counts())

Comment: @Submi - You are right check for updated solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to solve this,
As Submi Tried,

```
print (df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('test').value_counts()).loc[True].fillna(0)).to_frame().T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0   0.0   2.0
```

Comment: First option I would like to avoid, I have a lot of dfs and a lot of different columns in those. Second option works. only difference with @theletz solution is floats instead of int but this is not a problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Submi - To get exactly same output use reset_index. updated to the solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: 'test' in str(x)).sum()
```