# Count occurrences of certain string in entire pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 C1      C2       C3
 10      a        b
 10      a        b
 ?       c        c
 ?       ?        b
 10      a        b
 10      ?        ?
```

I want to count the occurrences of `?` in all the columns

My desired output is column wise sum of occurrences

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value counts for multiple columns at once in Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589829/how-to-get-value-counts-for-multiple-columns-at-once-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Might help to make it easy for people and provide the full dataframe definition.

Comment: @busybear I do not want count of all unique occurrences in the dataframe. I want specific `?` occurrences in all columns.

Comment: You can extract the counts for just `?` though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
m=df.eq('?').sum()
pd.DataFrame([m.values],columns=m.index)

   C1  C2  C3
0   2   2   1
```

Or better :

```
df.eq('?').sum().to_frame().T #thanks @user3483203

C1  C2  C3
0   2   2   1
```

Comment: `df.eq('?').sum().to_frame().T` should be a bit faster.