# Count unique strings by column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find how many times one of my four unique strings occurs in each column of my dataframe.

does anyone know a formula that would work for this?

Comment: Use `value_counts`

Comment: Please provide at least some kind of dataset with your attemps so we can have a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a'],
    'C': ['aa', 'bb', '', 'dd', 'do'],
})
   B   C
0  a  aa
1  a  bb
2  c  cb
3  d  dd
4  a  do
```

[value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method counts the occurrences of all values ​​in column '`B`':

```
df.B.value_counts()

a    3
d    1
c    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the source DataFrame is as follows:

```
               Aaa                       Bbb               Ccc
0          Mad Max           Sleeping Beauty      Seven Dwarfs
1  Captain America     The Magnificent Seven         Absolvent
2        Toy Story  The Fast and the Furious         King Lion
3     The Fugitive                Robin Hood  The Seventh Seal
```

The list of words to look for is (I shortened it to 2):

```
words = ['the', 'seven']
```

Then, to generate your result, run:

```
pd.DataFrame([ [wrd] + [ df[col].str.extractall(f'(\\b{wrd}\\b)',
    flags=re.I).size for col in df.columns ] for wrd in words ],
    columns=['Word', *df])
```

Note `\b` (word boundary anchor) in regex, both before and after the
word to look for.
This ensures that if you look for word *the*, there will be found all
cases of just *the*, leaving out e.g. such words like *there*, *Athena*
and so on.

Note also `re.I` flag, to perform case insensitive search (you have to
*import re*).

The result, for my sample data, is:

```
    Word  Aaa  Bbb  Ccc
0    the    1    3    1
1  seven    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

[value_counts docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

However, that function is only for a series so you would need to find a way to implement it across the columns you want unique value counts for.

[This example for value counts of entire df](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589877/7262049)