# Is there a way to determine if there is an uneven number of quotation marks in a string?

Tags: python, dataframe

From strings in a `dataframe`, is it possible to let the user know if there is an uneven number of double quotation marks?

Comment: `if s.count('"') % 2 == 1: print("Oh no!")`? For a dataframe, do it a bunch of times?

Comment: I would like to do this check for all columns in a dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value counts for multiple columns at once in Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589829/how-to-get-value-counts-for-multiple-columns-at-once-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

```
x = '"""'
print(x.count('"')%2==1)
```

output:

```
True
```

Comment: I would like to do this check for all columns in a dataframe

Comment: post your code and I could try to help. you can sum-up all the `count` over the columns and then check if it's odd for example

Comment: Okey, how about just counting all " in a dataframe? How do I do that

Comment: use this: `s = pd.Series(['$', 'B', 'Aab$', '$$ca', 'C$B$', 'cat'])
s.str.count('"')`, and sum over the result