# How can I reformat value_counts() analysis in Pandas for large number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataset that consist of hundreds of column, and thousands of row

```
In [119]:
df.columns
Out[119]:
Index(['column 1', 'column2',
       ...
       'column 100'],
      dtype='object', name='var_name')
```

Usually I did `value_counts()` for every single column to see the distribution.

```
In [121]:
a = df['column1'].value_counts()
In [122]:
a
Out[122]:
1     77494
2      5389
0      2016
3       878
Name: column 1, dtype: int64
```

But for this dataframe, if I did this for every columns, this will make my notebook very messy, how to automate this? Is there any function that help?

If you have other information, all my data is `int64`, but I hope the best answer can give solution that works in every cases. I want to make the solution answer in pandas dataframe.

Based on @MaxU suggestion, this is my version of simplified dataframe

```
df

id  column1  column2 column3
1         3        1       7
2         3        2       8
3         2        3       7
4         2        1       8
5         1        2       7
```

and my expected output is:

```
column 1   count
1          1
2          2
3          2
column 2   count
1          2
2          2
3          1
column 3   count
7          3
8          2
3          1
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197324/pandas-value-counts-applied-to-each-column

Comment: It'll depend on the way - you want to represent it... Can you add a small sample data set (with 2-3 columns) and your desired data set?

Comment: We need more information: at a *minimum*, include your data types (e.g. `int`, `str`, `float`?), whether ordering is a requirement, any output requirement (e.g. nested `dict`, `pd.DataFrame`, `dict` of `pd.Series`, etc.).

Comment: @MaxU I will edit my question

Comment: @jpp, thanks, will edit as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
In [83]: df.drop('id',1).apply(lambda c: c.value_counts().to_dict())
Out[83]:
column1    {3: 2, 2: 2, 1: 1}
column2    {2: 2, 1: 2, 3: 1}
column3          {7: 3, 8: 2}
dtype: object
```

or:

```
In [84]: for c in df.drop('id',1):
    ...:     print(df[c].value_counts())
    ...:
3    2
2    2
1    1
Name: column1, dtype: int64   # <----- column name
2    2
1    2
3    1
Name: column2, dtype: int64
7    3
8    2
Name: column3, dtype: int64
```

Comment: you will need `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',-1)' if data vary enough, but thanks, this is easier to look

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for loop.
Here all = list of all column names.

```
all = list(df)
for I in all:
   print(df[I].value_counts())
```

Comment: 'print' is lowercase

Comment: Edited,. It was typed on mobile hence it got capitalised

Answer (score 1):

You can produce your desired `value_counts` sequentially, convert to dataframes and write to csv:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('out.csv', 'w') as out:

    for col in df.columns[1:]:

        res = df[col].value_counts()\
                     .reset_index()\
                     .rename(columns={col: 'count', 'index': col})\

        res.to_csv(out, index=False)
```